# Bower is unable to download due to ECMDERR "Server aborted the SSL handshake"

Tags: git, ssl, bower

I am having a problem running basic Bower commands like install or list. When I run the error that Bower says failed, it runs fine. Is there any difference in how Bower uses git config?

```
▶ bower list
bower check-new     Checking for new versions of the project dependencies...
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake

▶ git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git | head
f52f83800624062443335a830112e3ae38b5c9cc    refs/heads/master
859e626c875659842d3582a0072fbb439b39f3a2    refs/tags/v1.2.0
4e6147d34c5e08bf9e7743bd36da35f19b265bf0    refs/tags/v1.2.0-rc.1
6ccd2d5b5b96506c98fe6158b7542dcf23a912a3    refs/tags/v1.2.0-rc.2
91aa0a12a19605b1166bf43d1444247a7320bd92    refs/tags/v1.2.0-rc.3
db9d2de12caaaa6603b06af504c6969a36431d0b    refs/tags/v1.2.1
0243df12570a70b5d07f83723e94e2a461982c99    refs/tags/v1.2.10
bd29251aa180d9cccff11dd583c928513662b101    refs/tags/v1.2.10-build.2136+sha.8ea8da4
fe72f28cc866777d0b07a6c44a66d75c2e3f22c9    refs/tags/v1.2.10-build.2139+sha.61eb426
b3b929d865c80e290935602587f2e0178b826262    refs/tags/v1.2.10-build.2140+sha.51a7f9d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is equivalent to network time out in terms of `bower install` command. Happens generally with a very long `bower.json` file.

You can try running this:

```
rm -rf bower_components
bower cache clean
bower install
```

Also, if you hit `bower install` again, you can see one of the following:

1. it has been able to download all the libraries and doesn't throw that error again
2. it throws the error, but for a different entry in your bower.json

Bower build should get resolved after a few repeated execution of same `bower install` command. No need to issue `bower cache clean` command again and again.

As an analogy, it's like trying to ping the same server after a network timeout. Solution isn't very clean but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your SSH keys on github. 
Try deleting them first. If it doesn't work, update with new generated keys.

I had this issue where I could `git fetch`, and `git ls-remote --tags --heads https://...` and this solved my problem.